# How to Cherry pick in Git if I have hash of particular commit?

Tags: git, github, hash, bitbucket, sourcetree

I have a develop branch and I need to cherry-pick a commit from my release branch.What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: assuming console, that should be just: git checkout develop-branch; git cherry-pick 8AF432..

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick <release-line commit>
```

Note that if you're just looking to cherry-pick the latest commit on the `release` branch, you can just `git cherry-pick release`.